# Simulate ant copy in rake

Tags: ruby, copy, rake

I want to copy some files with Rake, but compared to Ant this is kind of clumsy and my implementation is a bit stupid.

The source files have read only flags, I wish to copy files with write access (ant did this automatically).
If the target is not newer than the source, then I don't want to copy.

Here is my current code:

```
source = c:\perforce\read\only\lame
target = c:\deploy\files\stop\writing\read\only
FileList[source].each do |src|
  cp source, src.sub(source, target), :verbose => true
  chmod 0644, src.sub(source,target)
end
```

Ant would be

```
<copy todir="target" verbose="true">
  <fileset dir="source">
    <include name="*" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a bit different approach:

```
FileUtils.cp_r File.join(source,'*'), target
FileUtils.chmod_R target
```

But You were asking for:

```
if (FileUtils.uptodate?(src,trgt)) cp src,trgt,:verbose=>true
```

Comment: The issue with cp_r, is that I'm copying a specific set of files not just everything.  FileUtils.uptodate? is pretty cool.  Ill give that a go.  Ruby wouldn't happen to have a don't copy read only permissions would it?

Comment: there is function called FileUtils.install, which allows to set permissions during copy

Comment: Thanks, I knew ruby could do this ...somewhere... somehow